Proof of the limiting absolute error $e_c \leq e_a + e_b$
I want to prove that if 'a' and 'b' are approximations of 'A' and 'B' respectively (A and B are both positive) and $e_a$ and $e_b$ are the limiting absolute error of 'a' and 'b' respectively and if $e_c$ is the limiting absolute error of $C = A + B$ then:
$$e_c \leq e_a + e_b$$
So far this is my idea (using triangle inequality):
$$|(A-a) + (B-b)| \leq |A-a| + |B-b|$$
$$e(c) \leq e(a) + e(b)$$
$$(*)$$
on the other hand we know that:
$$e(a) \leq e_a$$
$$e(b) \leq e_b$$
$$e(a) + e(b) \leq e_a + e_b$$
$$(**)$$
we can conclude by (*) and (**) that:
$$e(c) \leq e_a + e_b$$
Now I should show that $e_c \leq e_a + e_b$
Thank you in advance for your help.

You have $e(c) =|C-c|=|A-a+B-b|$ but you do not seem to have defined $e_c$ except perhaps $e(c)\le e_c$ which is insufficient for your result. It may be affected by whatever you mean by  limiting absolute error.

Henry, $e_c$ is the limiting absolute error for c, which is a number that is not less than the absolute error of the number.

Your problem is that with "a number that is not less than the absolute error" there may not be an upper limit on $e_c$.

Henry, by definition $e_c$ (The Limiting Absolute Error) is not unique. if you remember in set theory we had sup(a+b) = sup(a) + sup(b). I want to use that and maybe apply it here, but here we know that only the less than or equal to relation in true.
